# Start scrolling on mouseover jquery jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to start scroll when user hover. I take a function reference from the question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651059/how-to-stop-jcarousel-immediately-on-mouseover-and-continue-on-mouseout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884610/jcarousel-how-to-get-pause-on-hover-with-autoscroll). I notice that even the callback function is not working with `initCallback` option. Am I missing something or I forgot something to put in the code. Here is example of code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egxLe0jb/)

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
  carousel.clip.hover(function() {
    carousel.startAuto();
  }, function() {
    carousel.stopAuto();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `jcarouselAutoscroll` plugin for that

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/b17uevar/)

INIT CODE

```
A(".example").jcarousel({
    auto: 1,
    wrap: "last"
}).jcarouselAutoscroll({
    interval: 1000,
    target: '+=1',
    autostart: false
});
```

Code for hovering

```
$(".example li").hover(function () {
    $(".example").jcarouselAutoscroll('start');
},function () {
    $(".example").jcarouselAutoscroll('stop');
})
```

Comment: u meant he fiddle is not working? dont forget to add that plugin code

Comment: its working perfectly in fiddle. can you give more information?